# How to detect if HDMI Monitor is switched off in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, hdmi

Is there any command in Ubuntu to detect an HDMI monitor? I have tried `ddclient` but it's not working.

The command I tried:

```
ddclient -p m/> Power control/
```

Comment: Did you try to use `arandr`? disconnect HDMI and type `sudo apt-get install arandr` - reconnect HDMI and check how that works?

Comment: i tried xrandr and this is working but i don't understand difference between xrandr and ddclient.

Comment: @BhumiShah [`ddclient`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ddclient) is a client for dynamic DNS services, it has nothing to do with monitors... Were you by any chance looking for `ddccontrol`?